# SQL Server Incremental Backups Split

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to recover a database where the incremental (log) backups are split between two methods (Carbonite/Zmanda and SQL `.bak` files).

When I try to use the restore wizard I get the following error for the Zmanda files:

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Cannot open backup device '{062FB61C-74FB-4EEF-9C95-39A84FB69BD3}'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.

Is there any way for me to make these "tape" backups accessible from SQL Server? The Carbonite backups seem to be grouped into single files for about 4 different databases but if there is alternatively a way to extract those logs that would be great.

I do have the full backup. Then after that I have this situation:

```
Carbonite-1   LSN-1 LSN-2
SQL-1         LSN-2 LSN-3
Carbonite-2   LSN-3 LSN-4
Carbonite-3   LSN-4 LSN-5 
...
```

So I have all of the files I need, I'm just not able to pull the incremental files out of Carbonite since they are in the Zmanda(?) format.

This is basically a case of incorrectly setup backups. The person who set it up was going for redundancy (two sets of incremental backups) but it looks like what actually happened was the backups were split between the two systems because of how SQL Server creates log files (only writes each entry to one place).

Comment: I've never tried from Carbonite, but all backups are in Microsoft tape format.

Comment: Do you have the full backup that was run before the incremental backup you are trying to use as part of the restore file list?  The error could be that it's trying to read the full backup file and it's not present in the restore list. You will need to complete set of backups starting with the full and all of the incremental backups that were made between the full backup and the incremental that you are trying to restore.  You won't be able to just restore the incremental backup by itself.

Comment: Are you using a third party tool for the backups?  I've seen issues doing restores if the version of the third party software is new on the sever that made the backup then on the server the restore is being done on.

Comment: Something tells me this note at the bottom of the Carbonite support page may apply to more than just Sharepoint. *Note: If you set up both Microsoft SQL backups and SharePoint backups, be sure to remove all SharePoint databases from your Microsoft SQL Server backup set. Failures may occur if the same database is being backed up by two different methods.*. [Caronite](http://support.carbonite.com/articles/Server-Windows-Microsoft-SQL-Server-Backup)